# Issue on Setting Bootstrap 3 Breadcrumb Content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/U6VJW/) and let me know why I am not able to update the Bootstrap 3 Breadcrumb content?

As you can see I update the Breadcrumb CSS rules in content to `"\e091"` which is (`glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right`) as:

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  content: "\e091";
}
```

but apparently this is not doing the job. Thanks

Comment: Assign the font to this.

Comment: Hi BootstrapThemer, can you please tell how to assign font here?

Comment: Koala_dev has the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `font-family` property to the Glyphicons font:

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  content: "\e091";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/U6VJW/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Koala-dev this is working but is there any way to center the arrows vertically as well?

Comment: @user3668817 try adding `vertical-align: middle;`